# How to return a redirect within Service which processes a form

Tags: forms, redirect, service, zend-framework2

I am working on a Service function with the purpose of processing a form used to authenticate an e-mail address.  As part of the e-mail address authentication integrity I am setting the temporary password to time out.

Step 1: User provides their account # and temporary password

Step 2: A Validator verifies both of these are correct.

Step 3: The form is passed to the Service for processing.  The first step of this processing is checking if the temporary password has timed out.  If the temporary password has timed out I want to re-direct the user to a form where a new temporary password may be requested.  I created this "if / then / else" to cause the redirect:

```
} else {
    return ['flash' => 'Password Timed Out' , $result['redirect'] => '/subscription-center-temporary-password-resend'];
}
```

The error I am receiving is

```
Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type Database\Entity\Member\Membership as array
```

$result is the variable assigned to the database query used to retrieve the temporary password expire field.

When I change the "return" to

```
return ['flash' => 'Password Timed Out' , 'redirect' => '/subscription-center-temporary-password-resend'];
```

the form submits to the redirect which is used to bring up the account authentication form (where the user provides their own password and sets account preferences).  I receive the error message:

```
SyntaxError: unterminated string literal
```

Comment: where are you getting this syntax error, javascript or php?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dealing with request/response (including redirects) is a controller concern and shouldn't be in your service layer.

You could throw exceptions in your service (one for each failure type) and catch them in your controller then redirect as appropriate.

An alternative would be to return a value from the service method that identifies the failure type and handle appropriately in the controller.

My personal preference is for the exception method.

The error you receive is due to trying to use the database result (an instance of Membership class) as an array.

The syntax error you've shown looks like it's JavaScript and you haven't provided enough context on that one to offer advice